# Python Regular Expression - Regular Expression that finds one pattern per line?

Tags: python, regex, expression, findall

Say I have the following lines in the file testFile:

```
Test Line in File
Test Line in File
Test Line in File
Test Line in File Line
Test Line in File Line
```

Is it possible to do a re.findall() that will allow me to find one instances of 'pattern' per line? For example, if I do len( re.findall("Line", testfile, 0) ), the program will return 7. I want it to return 5. I was thinking of something like "Line.*\n", but this will still return 7. Just to clarify, I want to avoid using:

```
count = 0
with open(testFile, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        re.match(pattern, testFile, 0)
        #etc
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's a strange question. If you want to counts lines that have a match, just count them. What do you want to be returned as a match if there are multiple matches in a line?

Answer (score 1):

For such a simple match, it's more efficient to use this...

```
count = 0
with open(testFile, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if 'Line' in line:
            count += 1
```

...which uses a [highly optimized searching algorithm](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/687295c6c8f2/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h) which is much faster (about 8 times faster last I checked) than using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the [Multiline](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) flag!

```
>>> s = """Test Line in File
... Test Line in File
... Test Line in File
... Test Line in File Line
... Test Line in File Line"""
>>> r = re.compile("^.*Line.*$", flags=re.MULTILINE)
>>> r.findall(s)
['Test Line in File',
 'Test Line in File',
 'Test Line in File',
 'Test Line in File Line',
 'Test Line in File Line']
```

However, in this case I would not encourage regex usage!

Comment: This answers OP's question, although it would be an inefficient way to search a file

Answer (score 0):

There's no point loading the whole file into memory to do an `re.findall` and by doing so you lose the ability to short circuit upon finding the first match

```
import re
with open('data.txt') as f:
    print sum(1 if re.search(r"Line", line) else 0 for line in f)
```

---

```
5
```

Comment: is `re.search` any faster than `"Line" in line`?

Comment: @1_CR no it will be much slower I'm assuming OP has a more complex regexp